# How to create dynamic reactive forms?

Tags: angular, forms

I have four components in the `shared` folder, which are **reusable**, which are:

[image]
Regarding the components that are in the `utils` folder:

These are **"dumb"** components which are reusable to **create forms**.

Regarding the components in the `forms` folder:

These are the creation of the specific form through the **"dumb"** components of the `utils` folder.

With this I try to create **reusable components**, but it generates the following `error`:

```
core.js:6272 ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:


    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });

core.js:6272 ERROR Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

      Example:


    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });
```

**1) What am I doing wrong?
2) Is all this architecture I'm trying to do wrong?**

**COMPONENTE EXAMPLE:**

```
   <app-form [formGroup]="sendMessageForm" [autocomplete]="'off'" [padding]="'0 1.3rem'">
        <app-input
            [formControlName]="message"
            [style]="'border-stack-big'"
            [type]="'text'"
            [placeholder]="'Type a message'"
            [alt]="'Type a message'"
            [minlength]="0"
            [maxlength]="105"
            [required]="true"
        ></app-input>
    </app-form>

    export class SendMessageFormComponent implements OnInit {
        value: string;
        sendMessageForm = new FormGroup({
            message: new FormControl(this.value, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(0), Validators.maxLength(105)]),
        });

        constructor() {}

        ngOnInit(): void {}
    }
```

**FORM COMPONENT:**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" [style.padding]="padding" [attr.autocomplete]="autocomplete" novalidate>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</form>

export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() formGroup: FormGroup;
    @Input() autocomplete: boolean;
    @Input() padding: string;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

**INPUT COMPONENT:**

```
<input
    [formControlName]="formControlName"
    [attr.style]="style"
    [attr.type]="type"
    [attr.placeholder]="placeholder"
    [attr.alt]="alt"
    [attr.minlength]="minlength"
    [attr.maxlength]="maxlength"
    [attr.readonly]="readonly"
    [attr.required]="required"
    (click)="onclick($event)"
    (blur)="onblur($event)"
    (keypress)="onkeypress($event)"
/>

export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() eventClick = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
    @Output() eventBlur = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
    @Output() eventKeypress = new EventEmitter<IKeypressEvent>();
    @Input() formControlName: FormControlName;
    @Input() style: string;
    @Input() type: string;
    @Input() placeholder: string;
    @Input() alt: string;
    @Input() value: string;
    @Input() minlength: number;
    @Input() maxlength: number;
    @Input() readonly: string;
    @Input() required: string;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    onclick(event: MouseEvent): void {
        this.eventClick.emit(event);
    }

    onblur(event: MouseEvent): void {
        this.eventBlur.emit(event);
    }

    onkeypress(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        this.eventKeypress.emit({ evt: event, value: this.value });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah.. this is not the way. Do a google search for ControlValueAccessor - that might help you.

Comment: I saw an example that the guy created a custom-input and inserted it: providers: [
{provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef (() => CustomInputComponent),
        multi: true
} ...

However he put the ngModel and according to the angular's documentation if I didn't get it wrong, the ngModel is a two data binding that is used for "model" forms in the case I'm trying to do reactives.

Comment: Custom controlValueAccesor inputs work very well with Reactive Forms. I use them all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it as follows ...

**I did some tests and analyzed the following:**

1. The same nomenclature **cannot be repeated** for `FormControlName`.
2. `FormGroup` **should be passed t**o both the `<app-form>` component and `<app-input>`.
3. It is **also necessary to pass** the entire form to `<app-input>`.

So it was as follows:

**Send-Message-Form:**

```
<app-form [formGroup]="sendMessageForm">
    <app-input
        [fmGroup]="sendMessageForm"
        [fmControlName]="'message'"
    ></app-input>
</app-form>

export class SendMessageFormComponent implements OnInit {
    sendMessageForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        message: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(0), Validators.maxLength(105)]],
    });

    constructor(protected formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

**App-Form:**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup"  novalidate>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</form>

export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() formGroup: FormGroup;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

**App-Input:**

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="fmGroup">
    <input [formControlName]="fmControlName"/>
</ng-container>

export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() fmGroup: FormGroup;
    @Input() fmControlName: FormControlName;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

**Now I just can't say if this is correct and if it can cause some kind of problem.**